# makefile compiler-output in Rule

Tags: makefile

I am using a makefile and the Eclipse-Output-Parser and therefor i need the output of the compiler with compiler-flags. When i remove `@` bevor `$(CC)` every file-compiling will print the necessary informations. This is definitely to much, because it is hard to see warning etc. Is it possible to print it only once?

```
$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(OBJECTDIR)
  $(TRACE_CC)
  @$(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(IAR_INCLUDES) \
  $(if $(findstring 1,$(OPTIMIERUNG)),$(CFLAGS_OPTI_ON), \
    $(if $(findstring 1,$(OPTIMIERUNG_SPECIAL)),$(if $(findstring $(<F), \
        $(PROJECT_SOURCEFILES_OPTIMIERUNG)),$(CFLAGS_OPTI_OFF), $(CFLAGS_OPTI_ON)),$(CFLAGS_OPTI_OFF) ) ) \
  $(if $(findstring $(<F), $(PROJECT_SOURCEFILES_SPRINTF_ALLOWED)),$(SPRINTF_ALLOWED), $(SPRINTF_NOT_ALLOWED)) \
  $< --dependencies=n $(@:.o=.P) -o $@
```

I tried some if-else-statesment without success.

Answer (score 0):

You could select one of your `*.c` source files, e.g. `foo.c` and:

```
SILENT := @
...
.PHONY: foo.o
foo.o: SILENT :=
...
$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(OBJECTDIR)
  $(TRACE_CC)
  $(SILENT)$(CC) $(CFLAGS)  $(IAR_INCLUDES) \
  ...
```

For all `*.o` targets `SILENT` would be `@` except for `foo.o`. If you do not know in advance the names of your source files, you can, instead:

```
FOO := $(word 1,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c)))
...
.PHONY: $(FOO)
$(FOO): SILENT :=
```

Note: as `foo.o` is phony it will be recompiled each time you invoke make. This guarantees that you will always get the echo of the compilation command. But as it could also fire other rules, select `foo.o` carefully. If needed, you can even use a *true* empty dummy `foo.c` file:

```
.PHONY: foo.o
foo.o: SILENT :=
foo.c:
    @touch $@
```

Comment: Ok. Sometimes foo.o doesn't have to rebuild but other files.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
 TEST_STRING1:=teststring1
 TEST_STRING2:=teststring1

 $(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(OBJECTDIR)
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(if $(filter $(TEST_STRING1),$(TEST_STRING2)),\
    ${eval TEST_STRING2="teststring2"} \
    $(CC) ..... , \
    @$(CC) .... )
```

Be aware of the commas. I used this form: `$(if $(filter $(VAR1),$(VAR2)),then[,else])`